# In bash, can I create an anonymous read-write pipe to a subshell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, io-redirection, subshell

I'm trying to pass a "resolution service" to a bash script as read-write file descriptor attached to another script.

So given a "service" like `capitalize`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do read line; echo "${line^}"; done
```

And a client like `client`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $1 >&3
read line <&3
echo "${line}"
```

I'd like to place a call `client foo 3< <(capitalize)` and expect the output `Foo`. This call fails with `client: line 2: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor`. I assume this is because the pipe exposed by `capitalize`, which has been assigned `fd3` and passed to `client`, is read-only and not read-write.

So I'm looking for a syntax that makes a read-write pipe that can be shared between the two shells. Maybe something like `client foo 3<> <>(capitalize)`, but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

---

Here's a simple example of `coproc` in action using the interactive shell:

```
$ coproc cap { read line; echo ${line^}; }
$ echo ${cap[@]}
59 54
$ echo foo >&54
$ read line <&59
[1]+  Done                    coproc cap { read line; echo ${line^}; }
$ echo $line
Foo
```

---

When I go to send the file descriptors to my client, I haven't figured out the syntax quite yet...

Assuming a `client` updated to use different file descriptors for input and output like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $1 >&3
read line <&4
echo "${line}"
```

Then I try this...

```
$ coproc SVC { ./capitalize; }
$ ./client foo 3>&${SVC[1]} 4<&${SVC[0]}
./client: line 2: 3: Bad file descriptor
./client: line 3: 4: Bad file descriptor
```

Why didn't the file descriptors SVC at 1 and 0 get copied into slots 3 and 4 and passed to `./client`?

Hm.. almost there..

Comment: You probably (do not) want [Coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html). You do not want them because they easily lock up because of buffering. But with very simple cases they may work.

Comment: Woot! Thanks. But why do they easily lockup? Is that because a coproc will block after writing to stdout, and so will not continue until someone drains their stdout? That's not unexpected, right? Are you saying that in complex scripts it's just hard to ensure draining, and if it blocks it's hard to debug?

Comment: Not only that. Even if pipes were boundary preserving (they're not!) and not buffering (they are buffering!), the command running in a coprocess may wait for input from the main shell before writing its reply, with the main shell not writing anything to it until it gets a reply, etc. But the most obvious problem is with commands which do their own buffering in userland: eg. if you change the `{ ... }` to `{ tr a-z A-Z; }` in the following example, it will not work anymore: `coproc uc { while read v; do echo ${v^^}; done; }; echo foo >&${uc[1]}
; read v <&${uc[0]}; echo $v`